# how will i pass the string name in php?

Tags: php, jquery, css

Hi have a problem here how can i pass the string name in php? here's my code

i want to pass the data to the input type using `$_GET` or `$_POST`

```
if(isset($_POST['pickup']) == NULL){
    echo "-";
}
else{
    echo $_POST['pickup'];
}
```

i want to pass the data into the input type how will i get?

Comment: Both this question and the code in it are not very clear.  Please explain your question better.  I suspect you're just looking for a form.  Also, isset() will never be equal to null.  It will be either boolean true or false (though true != null and false == null).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
<input type='text' name='pickup' value='<?=$_POST['pickup'];?>'>
```

Comment: hi i tried your code it says in the input type <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: pickupplace in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\limo-services-template\limo-template\edit_ride.php</b> on line <b>47</b><br />

Comment: That means that there is no "pickupplace" index in $_POST.  Should it just be "pickup" instead, as you have listed in your original question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(isset($_POST['pickup']) == NULL){
    $input = "-";
}
else{
    $input = $_POST['pickup'];
}
<input type='text' name='pickup' value='<? echo $input;?>'>
```

Comment: Hi it says unexpected variable i think the $input one

Comment: Hi can i send you my file my problem is in the booking.php and the edit_ride.php  can i ask your email add?

Comment: add me on skype ivisionglobal_macky need help badly

Comment: actually in the first page there is an input type box when the user inputs it will pass the data on the other page and also in the edit page all i want is to get the data that will pass on the input type please help

Comment: Can you please post a little of your form code so I'll can better help you, sorry I don't have skype installed and I don't want to install it.

Comment: hi i posted it did you see ? :)

Comment: Where did you posted that, I dont see anything.

Comment: i posted it in add comment i will post a new one instead

Comment: You can't post more then 600 characters in the comment.